# jQuery image rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery

One of my clients wants his logo in the header of the site to alternate with another logo.

So for example:

```
<img src="images/logo-1.png" style="display:block;" />
```

What would be the simplest way to alternate this with `logo-2.png`

We don't want a huge script, just a simple script which fades one logo out and another one in every 10 seconds, and rotates between `logo-1.png` and `logo-2.png`

Something with `setInterval` and `fadeIn fadeOut`? I'm not too sure

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure this could be simpler, but here's something that you could use as a starting point, if none of the many plugins suit your needs:

```
var img0 = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff",
    img1 = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/ff0000",
    current = false;
function switchImg() {
    $("#img").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", (current) ? img0 : img1).fadeIn();
        current = !current;
    });
}
setInterval(switchImg, 10000);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/CsK7s/).

Comment: Simpler? It's 258 bytes compressed, I'm sure it'll do :)

Answer (score 2):

You could position the images one over another and just fade them and play with their z-indexes :

```
    function switchLogo() {
    var activeImg = $('#logo .active'),
        nextImg = $('#logo :not(.active)');
    activeImg.fadeOut(500, function() {
        nextImg.addClass('active');
        activeImg.removeClass('active').css({
            opacity: 1,
            display: 'block'
        });
    });
}
setInterval(switchLogo, 10000);
```

By positioning them on top of each other and modifying the z-index you get a smoother transition.
Here's a live demo :

### http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/gFHMJ/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WHnLs/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Jquery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Comment: Probably the lite version https://raw.github.com/malsup/cycle/master/jquery.cycle.lite.js

Comment: Not sure who that was.. not me tho

Comment: I didn't think it was, obviously someone doesn't like jquery cycle?! Pretty sure my answer was valid.

Answer (score 0):

...Or [jCarousel](http://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jcarousel&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/&ei=eXimTqhmzc7hBLr8gR4&usg=AFQjCNFWtB2y_TqyE1RkbXzfdDr2XVTLVA)